# how to use a class of a different directory

Tags: c++

I want to use an object of the class C, in the class D.

The tree of directories of the program is similar to:

```
directory1/directory2/main.cc
directory1/directory2/classC.cc
directory1/directory2/classC.h
directory1/directory3/classD.cc
directory1/directory3/classD.h
```

I've included the header in classD.h with the absolute path of the classC, but if I try to run I get this error:

```
Undefined reference to nm1::ClassC::ClassC()
```

In classD I call the object in this way: `nm1::ClassC * obj = new ClassC();`
I added to the wscript the correct headers with correct paths.

ClassC make part of the nm1 namespace, ClassD make part of the `nm1::nm2` namespaces.

How could I do?

Comment: An undefined reference means you're not compiling all files or not linking them correctly.

Comment: ClassD is ConsumerWindow and have: 
`    #include "consumerwindow.h" 
#include "../mySimulations/Logger.h" //correct path 
namespace ns3 { namespace ndn { 
void ConsumerWindow::OnData(){ 
ns3::Logger * logger = new Logger(); } }}   `   
ClassC is Logger and have: 
`   #include "Logger.h"
namespace ns3 {
Logger::Logger(){}
}    `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that **each .cc file is compiled separately.** At compile time, they're told by headers `there is a function/class/constructor called x` but not the implementation details of that function/class, because that is in the `.cc` file which has been compiled separately.

At link time, you need to either dynamically, or statically link another library, or combine object files into the same executable. This is done by the linker. The error you are receiving there is because at link time, the class `ClassC` you have promised is there, by including the header, has not been found in any of the libraries or objects that you have linked against.

Your headers are fine. I can't really tell you how to link properly because I don't know what compiler/linker you're using. But look up how to add linker paths to your link command. Also make sure you're compiling every file, and that each compile is producing some kind of object output, then check what is consuming those.

Comment: But if I put the ClassC files in the same directory of ClassD, could be the same?

Comment: Provided that whatever is creating your library or binary is including that object in its list of objects to link against. The directory structure doesn't matter as long as each object file is listed

Comment: I compiled every file, I've the .o of every file.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
#include<file path>
```

or

```
#include"file path"
```

where file path is full file path with C:.... if you are using windows

Comment: He is having a linker problem, not a compiling problem